# How to call builtin SQL Linq functions in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a query written with Linq and EF Core 6 and I would like to call the builtin function `EOMONTH` on a date column.

Something like:

```cs
_context.Pet
    .Select(x => EOMONTH(x.birthDate))
    .DoStuff()
    .ToListAsync();
```

How can I actually get to call `EOMONTH` and any other builtin SQL function from Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EF Core documentation has a page that show [function mappings between LINQ and SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions).

As of EF Core 6, it looks like EOMONTH isn't yet supported, but you can [provide your own function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) like this:

```cs
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    [DbFunction(IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static DateTime EOMONTH(DateTime startDate)
        => throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Don't call EOMONTH directly. It must to be translated to SQL " +
            "inside of a LINQ query.");
}
```

```cs
_context.Pet
    .Select(x => MyContext.EOMONTH(x.birthDate));
```

Note, lots of different styles are supported by EF. For example, it could also be an instance method. Read the docs to find the best way that works for you.

Comment: Is this just for illustrative purposes?  Because all this does is push the problem from compile time to runtime.

Comment: No, no, that exception won't actually be thrown if you do everything right. EF will see the call to EOMONTH inside the LINQ query and translate it to SQL--never actually invoking the .NET method.

Comment: We (the EF team) tend to focus more on SQL functions that have a clear .NET equivalent. Other T-SQL functions are lazily added to [EF.Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions#methods) as users ask for (or submit PRs for) them.

Comment: This worked! But only if the method is inside my custom context. Is there a way to put it in a separate, static class just to keep things tidy?