# How to get a DbFunction to accept a DateOnly parameter in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-6.0

Yesterday I managed to call the SQL `EOMONTH` function from EF Core thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73140678/how-to-call-builtin-sql-linq-functions-in-ef-core), but now I need to call it using the new DateOnly type:

```cs
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    [DbFunction(IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static DateTime EOMONTH(DateOnly startDate)
        => throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Don't call EOMONTH directly. It must to be translated to SQL " +
            "inside of a LINQ query.");
}
```

I've already implemented the support for using as a column in the entities:

```cs
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Properties<DateOnly>()
        .HaveConversion<DateOnlyConverter, DateOnlyComparer>()
        .HaveColumnType("date");
}
```

but the above definition of `EOMONTH` throws the following exception when starting to run the API:

[image]

How can I get it to accept this custom type as a parameter for a `DbFunction`?

Comment: Just call it with datetime

Comment: @erikej Then I would have to use DateTime for date columns, and it would be really nice to not have to do that.